# Kernel dependency issue on Ubuntu 16.0.4

Tags: apt, kernel, dpkg, dependencies, removing

I'm new to Ubuntu system. My server runs on Ubuntu 16.0.4 and kernel is 4.4.0-98-generic as shown by `uname -r`. I have successfully removed some of kernel images, but I'm experiencing the issue with the linux-image 4.4.0-119. The the output of `dpkg -l linux-image*` is

```
$ dpkg -l linux-image*

Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                 Version                 Architecture            Description
+++-====================================-=======================-=======================-==============================================================================
un  linux-image                         <none>                  <none>       (no description available)
un  linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic        <none>>                <none>       (no description available)
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-97-generic         4.4.0-97.120            amd64                   Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-98-generic         4.4.0-98.121            amd64                   Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
pU  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic  4.4.0-119.143           amd64                   Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-97-generic   4.4.0-97.120            amd64                   Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-98-generic   4.4.0-98.121            amd64                   Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-image-generic                  4.4.0.119.125           amd64                   Generic Linux kernel image
```

It seems to me that the linux-image-generic points to 4.4.119.125, but the server was booted with 4.4.0-98. This is where I got confused. If I want to remove the image 4.4.0-119, it gave me:

```
$ sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic is to be removed.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic
```

If I run

```
$ sudo apt-get remove  linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic
```

```
[sudo] passwor for ...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package 'linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: thermald but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Adding -f didn't help. My question is, apparently 4.4.0.119 is not installed, but why is it in the output of `dpkg -l linux-image*` and how can I "remove" it? To make it even worse, I cannot run anything with `apt-get`. BTW, what does the first column of the above `dpkg -l` mean, for instance, `un`, `ii`, or `pU`? 
Any ideas whould be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need to remove it? Have you tried `sudo apt autoremove`?. If you want to go ahead, have a look at this https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu

Comment: I think you are asking the wrong questions (see [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). Seems like your real problem is that apt won't install anything you wish and you must diagnose the version conflict, not about uninstalling already-removed packages. Since you are new, have many questions, and need help troubleshooting a complex topic, you might find the interactive and mentoring format of http://ubuntuforums.org more helpful.

Comment: @Katu Thx. I tried apt autoremove multiple times; the error is the same: <code>linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic but it is not installed</code> I also tried all commands found at the link ../questions/2793 but none of them resolved the conflict.